# Android Get XML not returning the whole file

Tags: java, android, xml

When I log the value of my XML file that is being called the file is ending at the same place every time. It saves that incomplete data as a string and then passes it to my XMLfromString function which errors out and shows the exception. (See error below)

I am wondering if there is anything I need to change to make sure top read the whole file.

```
    String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(items);
    Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

public static String getXML(String roomID)
{
    Log.d(TAG, roomID + "PASSED");

    String line = null;

    try 
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://mywebsite.com/xml_data/" + roomID + "_meeting_info.xml?id=cacheSTOP3");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    }
    Log.d(TAG, line);
    return line;
}






public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
11-21 11:11:55.456: INFO/System.out(282): Wrong XML file structure: unterminated entity ref (position:ENTITY_REF &@211:21 in java.io.StringReader@44f6a130)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which line above is producing the error?

Comment: @Peter please see my edit above. I left out the second function which shows the exception when the xml is incomplete.

Comment: Code is ok. There must be something wrong with input XML. Check line 211, column 21. Put Xml through validator http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml, whether it is proper or not, Is there any tag which is closed or not. If possible tell us which line is 282, and also post your xml.